# Firestore one-time read using Flutter, i got to printing document data in console want to output it in UI

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore DB, inside 'location' collection i have 2 docs,(named as Europe,Australia) having a field 'name' with their string values (same as their document names).

I have worked with StreamBuilder and Streams before, but this time i dont want real-time calls, but just once.

I wanna print that 'name' field data of all the docs inside location collection.
This is what my UI code looks like:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  double spaceInBetween = 25;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    DatabaseService().getData();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text("data here")
      );
}
```

I wanna print all that documents data, with all their names using `ListView.builder()` on the HomePage.

This is my `DatabaseService` class (using the official FlutterFire Docs https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/ but didnt find what i was looking for)

```
class DatabaseService {

  final locationCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("location");

  getData() async {
    await locationCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc['name']);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Also wanted to know if there's any other way i could do this, using FutureBuilder or anything else, just wanna get field data from all docs in a collection from Firestore and print it (im still learning).
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is FutureBuilder. You can create a Future method which is going to get datas from Firebase servers and return it. After that you just create a FutureBuilder which is going to help you to show datas and if something wrong with the server or the internet connection you will not get any error messages because FutureBuilder will show an CircularProgressIndicator.

I made a demo code for you to demostrate FutureBuilder.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final locationCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("location");

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<String>> getData() async {
    List<String> name = [];
    await locationCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        name = doc['name'];
      });
    });
    return name;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
              future: getData(), // call getData method
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                List<String> nameList = snapshot.data ?? []; // create a local variable which is storing data from the getData method
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ListView.builder( // if getData method give datas listviewbuilder is going to show datas
                        itemCount: nameList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(nameList[index]),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // if something wrong with the server or with the internet you will see a CircularProgressIndicator
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks soo much for your help : ) got it done. Trying multiple field data now, by putting it in a different class, may want help : )

Comment: Please do check this @Ferenc .. i have posted it in detail here : )https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866185/how-to-convert-firestore-document-data-into-a-class

Answer (score 1):

In order to ensure you only get the data once, you can use a `FutureBuilder` and ensure you define the [future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) outside the build method (for example in the `initState`) so that it doesn't get called again whenever the build method is called.

> **FutureBuilder**
>
> ...
>
> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> the asynchronous task will be restarted.
>
> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Update the `getData` method of your `DatabaseService` class to this below:

```dart
 Future<List<String>> getData() async {
    final QuerySnapshot locationDataSnapshot = await locationCollection.get();

    final List<String> listOfNames = locationDataSnapshot.docs
        .map((QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) =>
            documentSnapshot.data()['name'] as String)
        .toList();

    return listOfNames;
  }
```

This code above fetches the list of documents from the `location` collection and [maps](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) them to a list of names, which is then returned.

You can then get define the `future` object to get this data in your `initState` and use it in your `FutureBuilder` like shown below:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<String>> _nameListFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameListFuture = DatabaseService().getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
        future: _nameListFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          final List<String> nameList = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: nameList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(nameList[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code : ) made me understand it a lot better, was wondering how would we put it in a custom class object (i.e when having multiple fields and their data), would it be like <List<CustomClass>> ? And then how would we map the field values? (eg. name, continent, population)