# How to convert Firestore document data into a Class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, theres some documents with fields like 'name' , 'continent' etc with their string values. Im using FutureBuilder in the main UI code, and calling the `getData()` function.

Here's my code

```
class DatabaseService {

  final locationCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("location");

  Future<List<HomePageModel>> getData() async {

    List<HomePageModel> listData = [];

    await locationCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        HomePageModel(
          docId: doc.id,
          continent: doc['continent'],
          name: doc['name']
        );
      });
    });
    print("this is listData $listData");
    return listData;
  }

}
```

This is what console looks like:

`I/flutter (  430): this is listData []`

And this is the HomePageModel class

```
class HomePageModel {

  String? name;
  String? docId;
  String? continent;
  HomePageModel({this.docId, this.name, this.continent});
}
```

I dont know how do i put these document data models retrieved from Firestore in `listData` thats why in the console `listData` doesnt have any data.
Thank you :)

Comment: can you please elaborate, with a code snippet.. im a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Param B.

I think the **problem** is here.

```dart
    await locationCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        HomePageModel(
          docId: doc.id,
          continent: doc['continent'],
          name: doc['name']
        );
      });
    });
```

The first issue is you did not make a new object instance. The second is you did not add your new object instance to the list.

**I did not test the code, but i think this is going to work.**

```dart
class DatabaseService {

  final locationCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("location");

  Future<List<HomePageModel>> getData() async {

    List<HomePageModel> listData = [];

    await locationCollection.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot){
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        HomePageModel homepagemodel = new HomePageModel( // the first issue
          docId: doc.id,
          continent: doc['continent'],
          name: doc['name']
        );
        listData.add(homepagemodel); // the second issue
      });
    });
    return listData;
  }

}
```

One more thing. I do not really know what is the difference between using `{` `}` and `?` in a class, but i have never used it. I make a class like this. But i think your class also works.

```dart
class HomePageModel {
  String name;
  String docId;
  String continent;
  
  HomePageModel(this.docId, this.name, this.continent);
}
```

One more thing, print is not going to work for a list of items. You need to use for example a `for loop` like this.

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < listData.length; i++) {
   print("Loaded data: " + listData[i].name);
}
```

Comment: hey @Ferenc, i got one more question : p   Please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236691/how-to-check-if-the-devices-time-is-between-two-times-in-flutter-from-firebase