# How to check if the device's time is between two times in Flutter from Firebase/Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In the Firestore project, I have documents in a collection containing data for shops, having fields like `shopName`, `shopAddress`, `startTime`(eg. 10 AM) and `closeTime`(eg. 10 PM) . (all strings for now)

When the user is browsing the app, i have retrieved the data from Firestore of the shops displayed in the app, now i wanna show that the shop is closed when the device's time is not between the `startTime` and `closeTime` of the shop. How do i achieve this?

So far I can detect the device's current time using dart package `intl` using this code:

`print("${DateFormat('j').format(DateTime.now())}");`

It gives output as follows:
`I/flutter (14877): 6 PM`

This is in `DateFormat`, and the data types stored in Firestore are strings.. I dont know how to compare them.. Do let me know if i have to change the data types in Firestore too.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create a hash map like this:
`hashMap=['12 AM', '1 AM', '2 AM', ... , '11 PM', '12 AM'];`
After that you can get the positions of `startTime`, `closeTime` and `actualTime`, and see if the `actualTime` is between start and close times positions.

Let me know if you want to give you a code example.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you use `24 Hour Time Format` and convert `startTime`, `closeTime` and `actualTime` to `int` or `double` ( if the shop close at 20:30/8:30pm), then you can easily compare them with `if`. *On your firebase server string format is perfect.*

For example you make a map and iterate it, and check if the `actualTime` is higher than `startTime` and lower than `closeTime`.

*I have never tried this code, but i think it is going to work.*

```dart
Map map = {'1am': 1, '2am': 2, '3am': 3, ... , '11pm': 23};
map.entries.forEach((e) {
  if(e.key == actualTime) {
    if(e.value >= startTime && e.value < closeTime) {
      print('Open');
    }
    else{
      print('Closed');
    }
  }
});
```

By the way, I think you should use `UTC`, because if you change the time-zone on your device, your app is going to show that the shop is closed, but in fact the shop is open, just you are in a different time-zone. You can easily implement this with this code.

```dart
var now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
```